GridView children not respecting explicit height?
SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                              child: GridView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: false,
                                itemCount: 4,
                                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4, childAspectRatio: 1),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Container(height: 25, width: 25);
                                },
                              ),
                            )

Despite setting an explicit height of 25 on the Container children when the Containers are rendered they're given a height of 83? And I can't stop the containers from overflowing the GridView which has an explicit height of 50?


Constraints goes down, size goes up, parent position the child.

Very helpful just repeating the rhetoric thank you

I think the SizedBox size is ignored by its parent because of missing alignment value. Try wrapping it in Align widget or any widget that can align it child/children: Row, Column, Container with Alignment property,...

You can set mainAxisExtent property for SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount or use
gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
     childAspectRatio: height / width,
     maxCrossAxisExtent: width,
),

